# android openGL grid artifact

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have an android app in which I use openGL to make some neat image effects.

The base setup is that I continually draw the buffer to one of two textures, then draw on top of that texture the next frame (essentially a simulation), to give the effect that the same image keeps getting manipulated.

I'm trying to add a fade effect to this, in which I darken the background, then draw on top of that, but I'm getting a very strange artifact from this. Here is my fragment shader:

```
 private final String mCompositeFragmentShader =
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "varying vec2 bTextureCoord;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
                "uniform sampler2D bufferTexture;\n" +
                "uniform float gamma; \n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  vec4 camera = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "  camera.r = pow(camera.r, 1.0/gamma);\n" +
                "  camera.g = pow(camera.g, 1.0/gamma);\n" +
                "  camera.b = pow(camera.b, 1.0/gamma);\n" +
                "  vec4 bg = texture2D(bufferTexture, bTextureCoord);\n" +
                "  vec3 color = max(camera.rgb, bg.rgb -vec3(.02, .02, .02));\n"+
                "  gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);\n" +
                "}\n";
```

with the relevant bit of code being:

```
    vec3 color = max(camera.rgb, bg.rgb -vec3(.02, .02, .02));
```

So I would expect light areas to eventually fade to black over time. However, instead of black it's fading to a magenta grid: 
[image: artifact image]

You can see that the gridding is different for each triangle being drawn on the screen (I'm only drawing two triangles).

Here is the vertex shader, just in case:

```
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
    "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
    "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
    "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
    "varying vec4 tempCoords;" +
    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
    "varying vec2 bTextureCoord;\n" +
    "void main() {\n" +
    "  gl_Position = aPosition;\n" +
    "  bTextureCoord = aTextureCoord.xy;\n" +
    "  tempCoords = aTextureCoord;\n" +
    "  tempCoords.y = aTextureCoord.y * ("+previewSize.height+".0 /"+previewSize.width+".0);\n" +
    "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * tempCoords).xy;\n" +
    "}\n";
```

Anyone have any idea what's causing this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Please post the full vertex and fragment shaders.

Comment: Also, your code excerpt is invalid. Count your parentheses :)

Comment: Whoops. I guess I shouldn't paraphrase code. Added actual code above.

Comment: posted vertex shader as well for reference.